# Windows-7 mouse and touchpad stops working, only restart helps

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, touchpad

On my Dell Business Laptop (probably 3 years old) the mouse randomly stops working in Windows 7. The windows pointer will not move, even though I move the USB-mouse or use the built in touchpad.

The facts:

- The mouse and the touchpad stop working at the same time (so its probably no hardware issue)
- Restarting windows will make touchpad and mouse work again
- Unplugging an Re-Plugging the USB-Mouse does not help
- Keyboard or any other components are not affected. Windows still responds normally, I can use my applications with the keyboard
- No Error Messages shown

Comment: Try the easiest thing first - try a new USB mouse.

Comment: Try checking the drivers in the Device Manager (Control Panel > System and Security > System > Device Manager).  It is relatively common for drivers to be updated.  You can tell which need to be upgraded because a yellow triangle with an Exclamation mark will appear.  Update the drivers first and then test a mouse that is known to work.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 other mouse: same problem

Comment: @slartidan - Check the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something to do with the mouse itself, I'm not sure how to fix it (possibly by executing `sfc /scannow` from a command prompt with administrative permissions), but it's possible you need to do a repair install to fully fix the issue. I've never heard of it, but the mouse process sounds bugged.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the drivers for the input devices as well as the USB ports (Control Panel > System and Security > System > Device Manager).  If the current mouse and a new mouse did not work...it could be the drivers are outdated and need to be updated. Also check to see if the devices have installed properly (Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers).